# COPY INTO SNOWFLAKE IGNORE "/"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wish to upload a file with field with text containing "\", but to ignore it while running COPY INTO.

e.g:
For the following field value: `\"before!!\' not!!`

I wish the data be loaded as :
`"before!!' not!!`

I have tried including ESCAPE='\\', Tried using FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"',
and ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD in all kind of variations, None of those options did the job.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the values of a field then you would need to do it as part of the SELECT statement e.g. using the REPLACE function.

This is documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but replace demands doing it to each field in a SELECT, I am looking for something more general,  Which will not demand doing it in each COPY command. Like the definitions when creating STAGE

Comment: No - there is no generic field value transformation logic that can be applied to the stage